# Free Royalty Free Stock Footage

Tags: video

So I came across this website http://www.dissolve.com/ and they provide 3 free Royalty free stock footage every month.

I was wondering if there are any other websites where I can get Free Royalty free stock footage?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stock footage search service](http://video.stackexchange.com/questions/12179/stock-footage-search-service)

Comment: Welcome to Video Production. You might want to try searching the answers that are already here before posting a question—there are already a few answered questions regarding stock footage that should help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several websites that do that. For example, [this one](http://allthefreestock.com/) accumulates free stock photos and there's also a video section. However, your best bet is to use a designated search engine like the [creative commons search site](http://search.creativecommons.org/), which will allow you to find material distributed under [creative commons licenses](http://creativecommons.org/). Before you use any of the found material, make sure to check which license it's using - some of them only allow non-commercial usage or require you to share any derivatives under the same license.